# Current Leaf-off HiRes Orthophoto Alternatives to Pictometry

Tags: orthophoto, pictometry

Our nonprofit organization has subscribed for several years to Pictometry's aerial orthoimagery. Where there is coverage (in most metro areas), the quality of the leaf-off imagery has justified the cost of the subscription ... until now.

Pictometry has announced a transition to a service now called CONNECTExplorer, and although it has some nice (minor) improvements, the manner in which the costs are calculated will cause our organization's subscription to go up between 5 - 10 fold. We like the imagery (and the customer service), but that sort of price increase is a deal-killer.

We've looked for alternatives, but so far, they have either not been leaf-off (NAIP, most govt programs, Bing, etc) or have not spanned the US (most county or state programs). It also helps to be able to easily see the image collection date.

For leaf-off, hi-res (6 or 12 inch/pixel) orthoimagery over much of the US that can be downloaded in georeferenced form, what other alternatives are there currently?

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for, nearmap offers high resolution 3" GSD imagery over the largest metropolitan areas in the USA and refreshes the data 2-4 times per year including spring (leaf off) collection. The PhotoMaps imagery is accessible through industry standard interfaces such as WMS or Esri Marketplace. We offer a couple of different purchasing options including per seat and volume, so you should be able to find a more cost effective option.

Comment: Self promotion is not really allowed on GIS-SE if you can give reasons why your service can provide the best answer to the question. http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior

Comment: Thanks. As you indicated, the coverage appears be (solely) the very largest metropolitan areas, based on http://maps.us.nearmap.com/ (which is a great to have online).